# Change path to file with Maven Ant

Tags: java, maven, ant

Im so new at Mavan and ant. I have simple project like this:

```
public class test {

    public test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "test\\template.txt"
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
    }
}
```

I want just change my String "path" form ant task.
Can i do that? If yes pls tell me how.

Comment: Ant and MAven are build tools. What you ask looks, more like different argument for the application. If you are new to Java development, leave Ant and Maven, rest fro enxt month.

Comment: Also split test classes from the Application classes

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Application {

    public Application() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage " + Application.class.getSimpleName() + " template-file");
        }

        String pathStr = args[0];
        File path = new File(pathStr);
        if (path.exists()) {
            System.err.println("Already a file exists at location '" + path + "'");
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
    }
}
```